# Java generics wildcard for different subtypes clarification

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I want to avoid explicit cast in my code, this is what I've done until now, but the compiler gives me some error and I don't understand how to fix it **without cast**.

I have a class with a map of listener, and some methods which notify the listeners:

```
public class MessageDispatcher {
    
     private final Map<String, List<ControllerMessageWatcher<? extends ControllerMessage>>> watchers;
     
     public void registerMessageWatcher(Class<? extends ControllerMessage> classToWatch, final ControllerMessageWatcher<?> controllerMessageWatcher) {
        this.watchers.computeIfAbsent(classToWatch.getSimpleName(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(controllerMessageWatcher);
    }

     public synchronized void receive(StatusMessage statusMessage) {
         List<ControllerMessageWatcher<?>> watchers = this.watchers.get(statusMessage.getClass().getSimpleName());
         if (watchers != null)
             watchers.forEach(controllerMessageWatcher -> controllerMessageWatcher.newMessage(statusMessage)); 
               // Required type: capture of ?      Provided:  StatusMessage <-- error here!   ^^^^
     }

     public synchronized void receive(UpdateDBMessage updateDBMessage) {
        List<ControllerMessageWatcher<?>> watchers = this.watchers.get(updateDBMessage.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (watchers != null)
            watchers.forEach(controllerMessageWatcher -> controllerMessageWatcher.newMessage(updateDBMessage));
               // Required type: capture of ?      Provided:  UpdateDBMessage <-- error here!   ^^^^
     }
}
```

This is the interface for the listeners:

```
public interface ControllerMessageWatcher<T extends ControllerMessage> {

    void newMessage(T message);
}
```

And this is the implementation of listener that I wish use avoiding casting:

```
public class Status implements ControllerMessageWatcher<StatusMessage> {
    @Override
    public void newMessage(StatusMessage message) {
        ...
    }

}
```

All works except the methods *receive* which gives errors (or unchecked warnings if I remove wildcards).

What I want to achieve is avoid explicit cast in every *newMessage* methods (I have to do this if I remove all generics part).

And avoiding errors/warnings when I call `newMessage` from `MessageDispatcher.receive()` methods (what I have now) (see comments in that methods)

This are `ControllerMessage`, `StatusMessage` and `UpdateDBMessage`:

```
public abstract class ControllerMessage {

    private String messageId;

//    ...  getter setter
}
```

```
public class StatusMessage extends ControllerMessage{

    private String aField;

//    ...  getter setter
}
```

```
public class UpdateDBMessage extends ControllerMessage{

    private String aField;

//    ...  getter setter
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very readable and it lacks some parts. Please provide the error compiler gives you, provide what exactly you want to avoid (which line of the code) and what is the aimed result you want to achieve. Also, what is `ControllerMessage`? `AckMessage`?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I've edited question, the `ControllerMessage` is only an abstract class for every message with common fields

Comment: Please provide that class, also we don't see what is `StatusMessage`. It's very hard to answer the question when we have to read and parse entire code. If you only have a particular question on some particular line, please provide that, with the clear log of error.

Comment: I've added the classes requested, the error is specified in 2 lines of comment in code.

Comment: See the answer I wrote below. I hope it'll make it clear for you. Please ask the questions in the comments if something remains dubious.

Comment: Your `newMessage( T t)` means that you need to call the method with a `T` not with a `ControllerMessage` so when your T is a `? extends ControllerMessage` you cannot call newMessage. You need `List<ControllerMessageWatcher<StatusMessage>> watchers`

Comment: @matt what about my solution (last answer edit) ?

Comment: I don't see any answers or solutions? The issue lies in your `Map<String, List<ControllerMessageWatcher<? extends ControllerMessage>>> watchers;` because you're going to get a `ControllerMessageWatcher` that requires an unknown class. You will *always* need to cast to use `void newMessage(T message);` with this design. Since you don't have any implementation details, I think your method signature should be `void newMessage(ControllerMessage message)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is fundamentally broken because of your use of reflection.

```
public void registerMessageWatcher(
    Class<? extends ControllerMessage> classToWatch, 
    final ControllerMessageWatcher<?> controllerMessageWatcher
)
```

This step, at the level of your API, you have made it impossible for the compiler to manage your inheritance.

A small improvement would be to make the type consistent.

```
public <T extends ControllerMessage> void registerMessageWatcher(
    Class<T> classToWatch, 
    final ControllerMessageWatcher<T> controllerMessageWatcher
)
```

Now we are keeping track of our class type, for better or worse, but we still need to caste to keep the classes in the map.

```
private final Map<Class<?>, List<ControllerMessageWatcher<?>>> watchers;

List<ControllerMessageWatcher<T>> getWatchers( Class<T> clazz ){
    return (List<ControllerMessageWatcher<T>>)watchers.get(clazz);
}
```

To avoid casting I would make

```
public interface ControllerMessageWatcher<T extends ControllerMessage> {
    void newMessage(ControllerMessage message);
}
```

I don't know what you're doing with your watcher that would new message to distinguish the type. This way you can have.

```
List<ControllerMessageWatcher<? extends ControllerMessage>> watchers;
watchers.forEach( w -> w.newMessage( message ) );
```

Then replace the abstract classes with interfaces.

```
interface ControllerMessage{
    String getMessageId();
    String getAField();
}
```

Now it is up to the specific watchers to grab the relevant information. You can also make default methods for fields that are  not relevant.